# why grid- "column: span 2;" does not change the size of the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am studying React, and in one of the exercises, creating a calculator, the teacher used the "grid-column: span 2". I made the code like him. However, the "span" in my "grid-column" does not seem to work. I already researched and it seems all right. Would anyone know why the "grid-column" is not changing the size of the buttons on the grid? I will be very grateful.

below the button css:

(I even put the green color on the button to make sure it is changing the right button. And despite changing the color to green it does not change the size)

```
.button{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  
  
}
 
.button:active{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
 
.button.double{
    grid-column: span 2;
    background-color: green;
}
 
.button.triple{
    grid-column: span 3;
    background-color: green;
}
.button.operation{
    background-color: #fa8231;
    color: #fff;
}
 
.button.operation:active{
    background-color: #fa8231cc;
}
```

Below the jsx code of the button:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Button.css";
 
export default (props) => {
  let classes = "button ";
  classes += props.operation ? "operation" : "";
  classes += props.double ? "double" : "";
  classes += props.triple ? "triple" : "";
  if(props.operation){
    console.log("funcionou OPERATION")
  }
  if(props.double){
    console.log("funcionou DOUBLE")
  }
  if(props.triple){
    console.log("funcionou TRIPLE")
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => props.click && props.click(e.target.innerHTML)}
        className={classes}
      >
        {props.label}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here the jsx code of the calculator, which is instantiating the buttons:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Component } from 'react';
import './Calculator.css'
 
import Button from '../components/Button'
import Display from '../components/Display'
 
export default class Calculator extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.clearMemory = this.clearMemory.bind(this)
        this.setOperation = this.setOperation.bind(this)
        this.addDigit = this.addDigit.bind(this)
    }
clearMemory(){
    
}
setOperation(operation){
console.log(operation)
}
addDigit(n){
console.log(n)
}
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="calculator">
                <Display value = "000" />
                <Button label = "AC" click = {this.clearMemory} triple/>
                <Button label = "/" click = {this.setOperation} operation/>
                <Button label = "7" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "8" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "9" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "*" click = {this.setOperation}/>
                <Button label = "4" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "5" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "6" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "-" click = {this.setOperation}/>
                <Button label = "1" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "2" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "3" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "+" click = {this.setOperation}/>
                <Button label = "0" click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "." click = {this.addDigit}/>
                <Button label = "=" click = {this.setOperation}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here the css code of the calculator:

```
.calculator{
    width: 235px;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px;
}
```

Comment: As a wild guess: Are the white spaces added correctly? Cause I think you get a string like 'button operationdouble' and not the required one for CSS like ''button operation double'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Button` contains an extra `div` and you need to add `display: grid` to this parent element:

```
export default (props) => {
  let classes = "button ";
  classes += props.operation ? "operation" : "";
  classes += props.double ? "double" : "";
  classes += props.triple ? "triple" : "";
  if(props.operation){
    console.log("funcionou OPERATION")
  }
  if(props.double){
    console.log("funcionou DOUBLE")
  }
  if(props.triple){
    console.log("funcionou TRIPLE")
  }
  return (
    <div style={{display: grid}}>      // <-- this line!
      <button
        onClick={(e) => props.click && props.click(e.target.innerHTML)}
        className={classes}
      >
        {props.label}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It worked very well. Thanks. I didn't think it would just be this div. Too much!